# Primefaces Datatable update footer go in loop

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am using primefaces 4.0. I have a datatable which simply 7 columns and each columns has an inputText which is an integer. I use the collector to add a row to the table. i want when i move from one input field to another and change the value the sum of each columns appear on footer. I managed to do this by using

```xhtml
<h:inputText size="2" value="#{rec.monday.tid}">
   <p:ajax event="blur" update="@form" />
</h:inputText>
```

The problem is that first request goes in to a loop and it doesnt allow to change the other values. I tried to only update one footer each time by using this code. It doesnt seems to work.

```xhtml
<p:column >
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="#{newRecord.record.monday.day}" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:inputText size="2" value="#{rec.monday.tid}">
                <p:ajax event="blur" update=":form:records:mon" />
        </h:inputText>
        <f:facet name="footer">
           <h:outputText id="mon" value="#{newRecord.totalSun}" />
    </f:facet>
</p:column>
```

```xhtml
<h:form id="form">

        <p:growl id="msgs" />

        <p:panel header="Create a new record">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" id="grid">
                <h:outputLabel value="time : *" for="txt_time"></h:outputLabel>
                <p:inputText id="txt_time" value="#{newRecord2.record.tid}" required="true" />

                <p:inputText id="txt_time2" value="#{newRecord2.record.tid2}" required="true" />

                <p:commandButton value="Reset" type="reset" />
                <p:commandButton id="btn_add" value="Add" update="records msgs @parent" action="#{newRecord2.reinit}">
                    <p:collector value="#{newRecord2.record}" addTo="#{newRecord2.records}" />
                </p:commandButton>
            </h:panelGrid>
        </p:panel>

        <p:outputPanel id="records">
            <p:dataTable id="recordsTable" value="#{newRecord2.records}" var="record">

                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="tid" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:inputText value="#{record.tid}">
                        <p:ajax update="total"></p:ajax>
                    </h:inputText>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <h:outputText id="total" value="#{newRecord2.totalTid}" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:column>
                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="tid" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <h:inputText value="#{record.tid2}">
                        <p:ajax update="total2"></p:ajax>
                    </h:inputText>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <h:outputText id="total2" value="#{newRecord2.totalTid2}" />
                    </f:facet>
                </p:column>



                <p:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="Operation" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:commandLink value="Remove" update=":form:records" process=":form:records">
                        <p:collector value="#{record}" removeFrom="#{newRecord2.records}" />
                    </p:commandLink>
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
        </p:outputPanel>

    </h:form>
```

Is the anybody who can help me? is it possible to update the values on client side?

Comment: Have you tried updating only your `<h:outputText>` ?

Comment: yes i am trying to do that by update=":form:records:mon"  then the loop problem is gone but it doesnt update the footer.

Comment: I tried update="mon" too it doesnt work it only work when i update the whole table but it goes to a loop.

Comment: What is supposed to be updated in `<h:outputText id="mon" value="#{newRecord.totalSun}" />` if nothing is changed when `blur` event happens?

Comment: it should be the sum of the values in this column. now the backend bean which is a method getTotalSun return the sum of this column by adding the values.

Comment: Can you provide a copy-paste-runnable [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to make your example clearer?

Comment: ok I added the short version of form. do you need the backbean also?

Comment: *to do that by update=":form:records:mon" then the loop problem is gone but it doesnt update the footer*, this seems to be exactly the same problem as I just [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524531/referencing-datatable-footer) about.