# Referencing dataTable footer

Tags: primefaces, facelets, jsf-2.2

I am trying to use Ajax updates triggered from a component within a `p:dataTable` to update the footer of the table. But no matter how I write my ID references in the `p:ajax` tag I don't seem to be able to get them right.

This is an example:

```html
<h:form id="formId">

  <p:dataTable id="tableId" var="row" value="#{testBean.dataRows}" rowIndexVar="rowIx">
    <p:column>
      <h:outputText value="#{row}"/>

      <p:inputText id="innerInputId" value="#{testBean.str}">
        <p:ajax event="keyup" update="tableId:footerId"/>
        <p:ajax event="keyup" update=":formId:tableId:footerId"/>
        <p:ajax event="keyup" update="@form:tableId:footerId"/>
      </p:inputText>

      <f:facet name="footer">
        <h:outputText id="footerId" value="#{testBean.str}"/>
      </f:facet>
    </p:column>
  </p:dataTable>

  <p:inputText id="outerInputId" value="#{testBean.str}">
    <p:ajax event="keyup" update="tableId:footerId"/>
  </p:inputText>

</h:form>
```

In the generated HTML I can see that the `outputText` in the footer gets the ID `formId:tableId:footerId`.

The reference from `outerInputId` works fine.

All of the references from `innerInputId` I expect to work, but they don't. In the generated HTML I can see that they are translated into the form `formId:tableId:0:footerId`. This would make sense if the footer was located inside the naming container of the current row, but it isn't as I can see from its ID.

I smell a bug here. Am I right? How can I work around it?

Or is this expected behaviour, and in that case why?

I want to do this to display the sum of all the cells in the column in the footer.

Relevant software: PrimeFaces 5.1, Mojarra 2.2.7, GlassFish 4.1

Comment: Updating a data table footer does not happen as one intuitively expects. See for example, http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=18347, http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6063, https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1558.

Comment: The links to provide seem related but they don't really solve my problem. I also want to stress the fact that updating the footer works fine from a component outside the table. It is when referencing it from inside the table that the ID:s get messed up.

Comment: I tested your code here with PF4 and JBoss7.1, it works perfect.

Comment: Thanks, henriquedsg89, that's a *very* interesting result! I have think about what to make of it tomorrow. Could you check the generated HTML to see what ID the Ajax `update` attributes reference?