# BlockUI is not triggered when trigger is in a p:column

Tags: primefaces

I am using buttons in a p:datatable and they are triggering a p:blockUI (PF 6.0)

When located in the footer of my datatable, the button does trigger the blockUI. When moved into a column, **it does not trigger it**

**BlockUI**

```
<p:blockUI block="blockPanel"
    trigger="myForm:myTable:myButton myForm:myTable:myButton2">
            Loading..<br />
    <p:graphicImage name="images/loading_blue.svg" />
</p:blockUI>
```

**Datatable**

```
<p:panel id="blockPanel">
    <h:form id="myForm">
        <h:panelGrid columns="1" cellpadding="5">
            <p:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{modelBean.myList}" var="entry">

                <!-- Some data -->
                <p:column headerText="Name">
                    <h:outputText value="#{entry.name}" />
                </p:column>

                <!-- Does not work -->
                <p:column style="text-align: center">
                    <p:commandButton id="myButton" actionListener="#{bean.method()}" />
                </p:column>

                <!-- Works -->
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton id="myButton2" actionListener="#{bean.method()}" />
                </f:facet>

            </p:dataTable>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</p:panel>
```

Why ?

The following workaround did not work for me:

```
<p:commandLink ... onclick="bui.show()" oncomplete="bui.hide()">
...
<p:blockUI widgetVar="bui" />
```

Comment: i know that it is sound very weird but try `trigger=" :myForm:myTable:myButton , :myForm:myTable:myButton2"`

Comment: It does sound weird, but did not trigger the BlockUI :(

Comment: did you add `blocked` to make a condition how the blockUi will appear and disappear

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: use my blockUI and tell me if it's working `<p:blockUI block=":IDObject" widgetVar="tbd" blocked="#{!ManagedBean.SomeCondition}" > ... `

Comment: It did not work. However when I put simply blocked="true", it is always blocked. So the problem still comes from the trigger.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reference p:commandLink in p:dataTable from p:blockUI trigger?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14893751/how-to-reference-pcommandlink-in-pdatatable-from-pblockui-trigger)

Comment: I had found that question too - but it is already 3 years old... I don't know what got fixed in PF6 with regards to this issue

Comment: 'Nothing' got fixed

Comment: And if you find related questions when looking for a solution that do not help or you do not know if it is related or not, [ask] states to post that. Saves us from doing identical searches.

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524531/referencing-datatable-footer

Comment: The workaround from the other p:commandLink question did not work for me, I assumed it was part of the same problem. I'll update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I used pe:blockUI:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/sections/blockui/blockPage.jsf

Answer (score -2):

What I mean : You don't have any value in your datatable. Put it one, you can create a backingBean return one value and add property value=#{myBean.value}. Also you have data on you datatable ! Test it

Comment: There are values in the DataTable. I left them out to focus on the problem. I updated the first post..